# PHP associative array with number as index

Tags: php, html, arrays

I have a form, with multiple select dropdowns. I named each one with a number.

**Problem**
When i do foreach loop over the results i can get the selected values, but i **cant** get the key? They start with 0 not with 1 as they should.

**HTML:**

```
<select name="1">
    <option value="1">Admin</option>
    <option value="2">Moderator</option>
    <option value="3" selected="selected">User</option>
    <option value="4">More</option>
</select>

<select name="2">
    <option value="1" selected="selected">Admin</option>
    <option value="2">Moderator</option>
    <option value="3">User</option>
    <option value="4">More</option>
</select>

<select name="3">
    <option value="1" selected="selected">Admin</option>
    <option value="2">Moderator</option>
    <option value="3">User</option>
    <option value="4">More</option>
</select>
```

**Form submit (var_dump):**

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "3"
  [1]=>
  string(1) "1"
  [2]=>
  string(1) "1"
}
```

**PHP**

```
$arr = $form_array;
foreach( $form_array as $key => $value )
{
   echo "The key is: $key <br>";
   echo "The value is: $value <br>";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because your array is numerically indexed. The *keys* are indeed `0`, `1`, `2` and the *values* are `3`, `1`, `1` respectively.

Read more about [arrays in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php).

From you comments, what it seems what you need is an array of the options, keyed so you can match them against your current array:

```
array(1 => 'Admin',
  2 => 'Moderator',
  3 => 'User',
  4 => 'More');
```

Comment: Oh,so how can i get names of select items?

Comment: You'd have to build an array containing those values and key them accordingly.

Comment: "The keys are indeed 0, 1, 2". This doesn't answer any question, which I think is "why?"

Comment: @Boann, it answers - *They start with 0 not with 1 as they should.* Post something if you have the answer *why*.

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce this behavior. Doing a var_dump of $_POST what I get is:

```
array(3) {
  [1]=>
  string(1) "3"
  [2]=>
  string(1) "1"
  [3]=>
  string(1) "1"
}
```

If you're var_dumping $_POST and still getting 0-based keys then it must be a version-specific PHP oddity, and I'd suggest using string keys instead ("value1", "value2", "value3", etc). If you're var_dumping a different array then it's probably some code you're not showing us which is reindexing the array.